# How to use UnicodeString.sprintf() mixed with std::string arguments?

Tags: c++builder

I have to add a feature to a project made in C++ with RAD Studio, and I can't seem to wrap my head around all of the different string types.

This compiles:

```
std::string batchID = "abc";
UnicodeString msg = UnicodeString().sprintf(L"Batch# %s", batchID.c_str());
```

But the variables contain these values:

```
[batchID] _Mypair { { { "abc\0\"\0\0€¼ÇwG\x01\0\0", "", "abc\0\"\0\0€¼ÇwG\x01\0\0" }, 3, 15 } }
[msg] Data :02787394 L"Batch# 扡c\"耀잼瞁Ň
```

Somewhere else in the code, the format string is `%ls` and it works! In fact, I copied these two lines from elsewhere that works, but this is what I get. Why? How to fix this?

Why are there 20 different string types all incompatible from one another!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are getting in `msg` is commonly known as ["Mojibake"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), which is caused by interpreting string data in the wrong encoding.

`UnicodeString` is exclusively a UTF-16 encoded string type on all platforms. Internally, the [`UnicodeString::sprintf()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString.sprintf) method is using the [`vsnwprintf()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Vsnprintf,_vsnwprintf) function, where the undecorated `%s` placeholder expects a C-style null-terminated UTF-16 character string (ie, `wchar_t*` on Windows, and `char16_t*` on Posix), but you are giving it an 8bit `char*` string instead.

To print a `char*` string using `UnicodeString::sprintf()`, you need to use the `%hs` placeholder (not `%ls`) instead (see [Format Specifiers in C/C++](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Format_Specifiers_in_C/C%2B%2B)), eg:

```
std::string batchID = "abc";
UnicodeString msg = UnicodeString().sprintf(_D("Batch# %hs"), batchID.c_str());
```

An alternative solution is to use the [`UnicodeString::Format()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString.Format) method instead, which accepts both 8bit and 16bit string types in its `%s` placeholder, eg:

```
std::string batchID = "abc";
UnicodeString msg = UnicodeString::Format(_D("Batch# %s"), ARRAYOFCONST(( batchID.c_str() )) );
```

Alternatively, `UnicodeString` can be constructed from a `char*` string, so you can prepare the `msg` content using just `char` data, and then construct a final `UnicodeString` at the end, eg:

```
std::string batchID = "abc";
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "Batch# " << batchID;
UnicodeString msg = oss.str().c_str();
```

```
std::string batchID = "abc";
UnicodeString msg = ("Batch# " + batchID).c_str();
```

Or, using the [{fmt} library](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html) (until C++Builder adds support for C++20's [`std::format()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format)):

```
std::string batchID = "abc";
UnicodeString msg = fmt::format("Batch# {}", batch).c_str();
```

Otherwise, just convert the `std::string` by itself to `UnicodeString` and concatenate it, eg:

```
std::string batchID = "abc";
UnicodeString msg = _D("Batch# ") + UnicodeString(batchID.c_str());
```

Comment: I think I understand why RAD is using their own `AnsiString` and `UnicodeString` implementations, but I prefer the `std::string` and `std::wstring` implementations and utilities. Thank you for the explanations, the `%hs` format worked quite well!

Comment: @YanickRochon `(Ansi|Unicode)String` are native Delphi string types. They exist in C++Builder for interop compatibility with Delphi code, as D/CB share common frameworks. `std::(w)string` are standard C++ string types, Dephi can't use them.